# Close on-screen keyboard, and THEN navigate to new screen (to ensure keyboard doesn't infringe on size of new screen)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, soft-keyboard

Title sums it up well. In Flutter, you can close the keyboard by removing the focus from it:

```
  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

And you can navigate to a new screen like so (many ways, just an example):

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('routeName');
```

**However, you can't wait for the keyboard to close before navigating to a new screen.**

I'd like to do something like this:

```
await FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('routeName');
```

^ This doesn't work because you can't `await` `.unfocus()`.

or:

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('routeName');
```

^ This doesn't work because you can't use `BuildContext` across `async` gaps.

How does one wait for the keyboard to disappear before navigating? Because, currently, closing the keyboard at the same time as navigating means the screen you're navigating to experiences a short period where the on-screen keyboard is inhibiting the new screen from being full size. This looks ugly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Write this in the Scaffold of the next(or prev) screen

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you go in new screen run the code below in initState function of new screen.
This help you to close the onscreen keyboard whenever you visit new screen.

```
@override
void initState(){
   FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
}
```

Comment: Good attempt, but doing that throws a bunch of exceptions referencing inherited widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the keyboard to close before navigating.

```
void goBack() {
   FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

   ///Wait for the keyboard to close before navigating
   Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
       Navigator.of(context).pop();
   });
}
```